# WSDL Method don't take the certificate given

Tags: asp.net, web-services, certificate, wsdl

I'm working on a program on Visual Studio, supposed to contact a Webservice (not mine) with the given WSDL. The service provided me a certificate and the certification chain and all of theses are installed and valid.

Whenever i try to use the wsdl method "search", i encounter an error saying
`The message received was unexpected or badly formatted`
followed by
`The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel`

I tried with SOAPUI, giving the certificate in SSL Keystore, works perfectly.

In Visual Studio, I tried to make an HTTP POST request, passing the XML as a string, and the certificate in the handler, it works good as well. The networks logs say this :

`System.Net Information: 0 : [19260] TlsStream#11429296::.ctor(host=webservice.com, #certs=1, checkCertificateRevocationList=False, sslProtocols=None)`

But whenever I use the wsdl method as such :

```
WebService client = new WebService();
client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = certificate;
OutputData Reponse = client.search(Data);
```

the certificate appears loaded into the Channel in debug (while hovering it in VS), but the networks logs show this :

`System.Net Information: 0 : [11260] TlsStream#16118003::.ctor(host=webservice.com, #certs=0, checkCertificateRevocationList=False, sslProtocols=None)`

I've tried putting Tls12, Expect100Continue, tried to load the certificate by file or by store... correct me if i'm wrong, but the certificate appears loaded and ready to go in debug till the request, but the logs show that it seem to be lost in the process, so it seem fair that the webservice refuse my request without the certificate.

Did anyone encountered this before, or am i missing something ?